# writeExceptionsToEventLog error

Tags: asp.net, membership

I have this error message.
The parser error message :attribute is not recognized writeExceptionsToEventLog
What do I wrong?

[image: Parser error message]

This is my code in web.config

```
<membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SqlMembershipProviderOther" 
        requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         connectionStringName="ConnectionString" applicationName=""
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
        enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true"
        requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed"
        minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" writeExceptionsToEventLog="false"
        minRequiredPasswordLength="8" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
        passwordAttemptWindow="10" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="8"
           />
      </providers>
    </membership>

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
     />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Try one thing... Rebuild/Close and Reopen the project Then build properly.Run.

If nt working , we have 2nd solution ,to add provider name if not added in connectionstring.

Comment: Solution 1 doesn't work, in connectionString  I got this: <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Answer (score 0):

Try one thing... Rebuild/Close and Reopen the project Then build properly.Run. If nt working , we have 2nd solution ,to add provider name if not added in connectionstring

Comment: Solution 1 doesn't work, in connectionString I got this: <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> it doesn't work yet

Comment: what do you means  ths... ??  defaultProvider="SqlMembershipProvider"

Comment: No idea, but 2nd solution add provider name if not added in connectionstring Can you give a example?

Comment: Because default provider is not needed.. More then Membership providers we can use  with declaring any default. Just keep <membership> .. remove attributes from that.

Comment: Can you please post you web.config file contents as it ... here (Hide you password)

Comment: Here is my web.config file
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LLRvl7HOWLGVzJ0Hrgt9ELyK5NQQHit--LGcY5bd5Ms/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SqlMembershipProviderOther" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ConnectionString" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>  add ths lines.. after <membership>..</membership>

Comment: It doen't work you can edit the google doc file? pls 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LLRvl7HOWLGVzJ0Hrgt9ELyK5NQQHit--LGcY5bd5Ms/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LLRvl7HOWLGVzJ0Hrgt9ELyK5NQQHit--LGcY5bd5Ms/edit?usp=sharing  ..now check,.

Comment: have u checked Stack trace ? What is inner exception for this error

Comment: No i have no idea, how can i see this?

Comment: while run application handle try ...catch (Exception e)...Put breakpoint over exception catch { string abc=e.GetBaseException().ToString(); } block ... and